# Cryptography Upgrade Issue on OSX

Tags: python, pip, scrapy, openssl

I am trying to install Scrapy, but I am running into an openssl error. All forums seem to suggest that the problem should be solved by updating cryptography, but I am also having an error upgrading it.

I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.1. I've updated my xcode, pip, and brew. How do I fix this?

```
$ pip install cryptography

WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into an error.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (2.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: enum34; python_version < "3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: asn1crypto>=0.21.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (0.23.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: ipaddress; python_version < "3" in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cryptography) (1.0.18)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography) (2.18)
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x10e937230>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)) - skipping
```

```
$ pip install Scrapy

WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into an error.
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
From cffi callback <function _verify_callback at 0x10f9acc08>:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 309, in wrapper
    _lib.X509_up_ref(x509)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'X509_up_ref'
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),)': /simple/scrappy/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is a complex interaction between a bunch of dependencies that ultimately breaks pip's ability to fetch things over TLS, but the easy fix is to use a browser to download the right wheel file from https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files and then type `pip install /path/to/wheel/wheel-file.whl`. As of this writing the wheel file that should work for you is `cryptography-2.8-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, except I had to make one tweak because my current user profile apparently did not have access to the folder with the file - that's a separate issue for another day I guess. 

Anyways, this worked for me: `sudo -H pip install cryptography-2.8-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl`